# How to upload a CSV file to Onedrive using API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to upload a CSV file to my Onedrive for test purpose but I can't figure out what's the `/content` at the end of the URL endpoint showed here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/addressing-driveitems?view=odsp-graph-online

So far what I have is : `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drives/root:/{folderName}/test.csv:/content`

But I'm getting the error :

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Resource not found for the segment 'content'.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-07-16T16:01:42",
            "request-id": "bf4490df-5689-4016-b609-d85a3d6e8945",
            "client-request-id": "ce01693e-ce87-61d4-c23b-79a28251818c"
        }
    }
}
```

Which seems legit because I didn't put any real contect inside, but I don't see how I can put a csv file inside a URL. I'm not sure I can have access to its binary value as I'm making the request from a cloud solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referencing `/drives` (plural) without providing a Drive Id.

If you're looking to upload to your default OneDrive, you want to use `/drive` (singular):

```
PUT /me/drive/root:/{folderName}/test.txt:/content
```

Comment: And is there a way to write into this file using API ? Or create maybe and xlsx file and use the add row API ?